# Teenage time travel movie (or series) with a watch like time machine

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am looking for a teenage (or child) time travel movie or series I have watched as a child in late 90's or early 2000's. My memories are quite vague, but here are the details as I remember them:

- Protagonist was a teenage boy.
- The boy had a title like Master, King or something of Time.
- He was using a watch like device to travel in time.
- The device had a 12 hour charging period.
- There might be some sort of aliens (or weird creatures).
- The movie was probably from 80's or early 90's.
- It was a live action movie with some poor cgi.

This is all I can remember. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this live-action or animated?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was a long-time observer, but now I am a first time contributor :)
I have edited the question and added the detail you have asked.

Comment: I have closed your question as a Duplicate, as we've had it before and our policy for `story-identification` is to close for questions with the same answer. ^_^ We get this one fairly often, actually.

Comment: All good. It makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!*, a six episode film series released in 1995 and 1996.

Point 1), [Corbin Allred](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0021607/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) was born May 25, 1979 according to IMDB.

*[Josh Kirby...Time Warrior! Chap. 1: Planet of the Dino-Knights](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113484/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_rdat)* was released 24 October 1995, when Corbin Allred was 16 years, 4 months, and 29 days old. And *[Josh Kirby...Time Warrior! Chap. 6: Last Battle for the Universe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116716/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_rdat)* was released on 21 May 1996 when Corbin Allred was 16 years, 11 months, and 26 days old.

In contrast, [Meeno Peluce](https://imdb.com/name/nm0671375/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) was born February 26, 1970 and so was 12 years, 7 months, and 7 days old when the first episode of *Voyagers!* was broadcast on 3 October 1982 and 13 years, 4 months, and 14 days old when [the last episode was broadcast on 10 July 1983](https://imdb.com/title/tt0083500/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1).

So Corbin Allred was more of a teenage actor in *[Josh Kirkby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)* than Meeno Peluce was in *[Voyagers!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyagers!)* (1982-1983).  And Josh Kirby is described as 14 years old while [Jeffrey Jones](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3) is described as 11 years old and 12 years old.

Point 2) Josh Kirby has a title, "Time Warrior" - it's right there in the title of the series  *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!* - though I don't know whether anyone calls Josh that or any other title in the actual films.

Point 3) I don't remember Josh Kirby using a time travel watch - I think instead he used a timeship.

Point 4) I don't remember anything about the charging periods - if any - of the time travel devices in either *Voyagers!* or *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!*.

Point 5) As far as I remember *Voyagers!* was set entirely in Earth history so there were no prehistoric or otherworldy creatures or monsters.  But Josh Kirby visited several worlds and met creatures, monsters, and alien people.

Point 6) *Voyagers!* was first broadcast in 1982-83, and *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!* was released in 1995-1996.

Point 7) Both were live action, and both had special effects.  *Voyagers!* was too early for CGI, while *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!* was late enough to possibly have bad CGI.

And statistically there should have been other movies and tv shows made in 1980 to 2000 with boy time travelers.  The main time travel series was the British *Dr. Who*, but only one of his companions was a teenage boy, [Adric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adric), in 1980-1982. The main American time travel series *The Time Tunnel* (1966-1967) could have been rerun in 1980-2000, but the protagonists were adults.

A famous movie about time traveling boys is the Czech *[Journey to the Beginning of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Beginning_of_Time)* (1955), but they float on a raft down a river which mysteriously takes them back in time and have no time machine.

It is possible the OP saw both *Voyagers!* and *Josh Kirby...Time Warrior!* and is mixing them up in their memory, which would produce most of the 7 points they remember.  Or maybe they saw one or both of them and also remember details from other kid time travel movies, tv shows, tv movies, videos, etc. they may have seen during that period.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good match.

Comment: WOW. That is it - Josh Kirby. As you have said, I have probably mixed up some details with some other movie/series. I have looked at the imdb pages of the movies and I have distinctly remembered little sidekick alien and mushroom people from one of the movies. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for, but there was a 1-season time-travel TV show in the early 1980s called [*Voyagers!*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/), in which a watch-like device called an "Omni" was used to travel through time.  One of the 2 leads (the smarter one, who got them *out* of trouble) was 12-year-old Jeffrey Jones, who had been accidentally picked up by the older (brawnier but less smart) Phineas Bogg.

This matches your points numbers 1, 3 and 6 maybe 7 (but it's not actually CGI), but not point 2 or 5.  (I don't know about 4.)

[image: DVD release cover of "Voyagers!" showing the 2 leads inset in the watch-like face of the Omni.]

Comment: One of my favourites growing up!

Comment: @DavidW  I don't remember Meeno Peluce as a teenager in this,   Acording to IMDB, he was born February 26, 1970 https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0671375/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1, while Voyagers! was broadcast from 3 october 1982 to 10 July 1983. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1  So Peluce was 12 & 13 when his episodes were filmed, and the character Jeffery Jones was 12 in the first episode.

Comment: The kid wore the same shirt in *every episode*.